# Why does JavaScript have the Math object?

Tags: javascript, math

In many languages, to find cosine, you use `cos(x)`. But in JavaScript, you must use `Math.cos(x)`. Why doesn't JavaScript spare us the 5 characters in `Math.`, both making it easier to type and easier to read?

I have tried to Google this multiple times, and found no answers. Is there any practical reason for this that I have not yet found?

So far, there are three reasons I can think of:

1. The creators of JavaScript want to ensure that the math functions do not coincide with other functions users create (Like a function called 'cos()` that calculates, say, cosecant)
2. The creators of JavaScript thought that `Math` would make the code more readable
3. The creators of JavaScript perhaps didn't want any functions that have `window` as a parent (Though `alert` and `prompt` make this unlikely)

Comment: The global scope is already overloaded enough IMO

Comment: I'm honestly surprised nobody's asked this before

Comment: If you wish to use certain Math functions often and don't like repeating the `Math.` part, feel free to extract the standalone properties first. `const { cos } = Math;`

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms Stack Overflow isn't a good place for "why did the designers of language X do Y" questions. The motivations behind such decisions are often not public knowledge and SO is a place for solving programming problems, not documenting history.

Comment: If you want my guess, it may have something to do with Java's `Math` class, since the executives in charge of creating JavaScript wanted something that looked like Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hold the math functions without polluting the global namespace.

Comment: But polluting the global namespace is fine as long as it saves 5 characters IMO

Comment: `But polluting the global namespace is fine as long as it saves 5 characters IMO` if it pisses you of, just put all Math functions into the global space yourself : const cos = Math.cos  and you're done.

Comment: OP asked why the language was designed this way. Do you have any citation for the claim that it was done for this reason, or are you just guessing?